# Add Interceptor from an existing OkHttpClient

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I have already built an instance of `OkHttpClient`. How do I add an interceptor to it? (I am also using Retrofit)

I wish to add my authorization token to it. I currently get the following error:

```
Error creating evaluation class loader: com.intellij.debugger.engine.evaluation.EvaluateException: Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception.
java.lang.NullPointerException: parentLoader == null && !nullAllowed
```

When I do:

```
okHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder().addNetworkInterceptor(new Interceptor()
{
    @Override
    public Response intercept(final Chain chain) throws IOException
    {
        final Request request = chain.request();
        Request newRequest;

        newRequest = request.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, String.format("Bearer %s", "Bob"))
                            .build();
        return chain.proceed(newRequest);

    }
}).build();
```

Comment: If you have instant run enabled, then do a clean/rebuild

Comment: It doesn't like it if I add an intercept when the OKHttpClient has already been made.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here though, so this is rather odd.